# How to make a function can be called only by specific class in swift?

Tags: swift

I have two frameworks A and B. I have a public function inside B called getMap() which returns a copy of a map(which is a private variable in B). So I call getMap() in A to get this value. This is fine because it's a copy so whatever I do to the returned value it doesn't affect the actual variable inside B.

Now I did some processing to this value, I need to pass it back to B. Here is the problem: In order to pass it back, it has to be a public function, but I don't want other frameworks or application to call this function because only A should be making changes to this map value.

Is there any way to specify in B that only if A is calling the function then the value should be set, otherwise ignoring anyone else who is using this function? I've heard you can use delegate/protocol to achieve this but I don't understand.

Comment: Read more about Access Control

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

Comment: I don't see how the delegate pattern would help to solve your specific question. However, you might want to think your architecture over. What's the reason why only one class should be able to call a function of another class? Do you have a concrete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be able to achieve this using delegate/protocols. The protocol will still have to be public which means any class could implement the protocol but the simple solution to this would be to just not implement it any other class.

You would create the the protocol in framework B like this:

```
protocol FrameworkBDelegate {
     func sendMapChanges(map: Map)
}
```

Then call the delegate method when you're ready send it back to the other framework:

```
func changeMap() {
     var map = frameworkA.getMap()

     // Do stuff to map...

     delegate.sendMapChanges(map: map)
}
```

I don't want to write a whole tutorial on how implement delegation so here's a good one from Swift by Sundell: [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/delegation-in-swift)
Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Well I can control whether if they decide to implement the protocol if someone else decides to implement it then they can still make changes to the map value. Is there any way to check like class name or file name to make sure it is only coming from the specific class that is permitted to change?

Comment: You could force them to send their class through the initializer and check if the class is of type FrameworkB. I haven't done this in Swift but I've seen it done in other languages like Java and C#.

Comment: But I don't think there is a fool's proof way of doing what you are doing, especially with frameworks. If you're the developer then you should be able to control who can call what functions since you are writing the code. There are ways to reduce the chance of it happening but no brick wall that stops everything except what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up checking the class type description. Unless somebody really wants to create the whole module structure then I think I am good :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box.
If you create a Framework than you have to decide if a method/class needs to be public or not. If a method is public than there isn't an out of the box solution which delivers a bullet proof solution which solves your requirement. In the end the method is public to ALL consumers of Framework B.

So, you will end up implementing some kind of access control mechanisms within Framework B. This means that Framework A needs to authenticate itself in some way (access code etc.).

The `delegate` pattern will not solve your issue as well, hence it also has to be public, so that Framework A can use it. However, if it's public than all consumers of Framework B can use it.